# Why does this multi-threaded program get blocked?

Tags: c, multithreading, webserver, mutex, condition-variable

This is my attempt of implementing multi-threading in a web server.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "request.h"
#include "io_helper.h"

char default_root[] = ".";
int open_connections = 0;
int n_buffers = 1;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond_empty;
pthread_cond_t cond_full;
int *conn_fds;

//Buffer consumer
void *manage_conn() {
    while(1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_buffers; ++i)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            while(!open_connections) {
                printf("IN.\n");
                pthread_cond_wait(&cond_full, &mutex);
                printf("OUT.\n");
            }
            if(conn_fds[i]) {
                request_handle(conn_fds[i]);
                close_or_die(conn_fds[i]);
                conn_fds[i] = 0;
                open_connections--;
                pthread_cond_signal(&cond_empty);       
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            //printf("New connection closed.\n");   
        }   
    }   
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    enum {
        FIFO,
        SFF
    };
    int c;
    char *root_dir = default_root;
    int port = 10002;
    int n_threads = 1;

    int schedalg = FIFO;
    
        while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "d:p:t:b:s:")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'd':
            root_dir = optarg;
            break;
        case 'p':
            port = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 't':
            n_threads = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'b':
            n_buffers = atoi(optarg);
            printf("This.\n");
            break;
        case 's':
            if(!strcmp("FIFO", optarg)) schedalg = FIFO;
            else if(!strcmp("SFF", optarg)) schedalg = SFF;
            else {
                printf("Invalid scheduling algorithm.\n");
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "usage: wserver [-d basedir] [-p port]\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    pthread_t *cid = malloc(n_threads * sizeof(*cid));
    conn_fds = malloc(n_buffers * sizeof(*conn_fds));
    for(int i = 0; i < n_buffers; i++) {
        conn_fds[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n_threads; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&cid[i], NULL, manage_conn, NULL);
    }

    // run out of this directory
    chdir_or_die(root_dir);

    // now, get to work
    
    int listen_fd = open_listen_fd_or_die(port);
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
        int client_len = sizeof(client_addr);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while(open_connections >= n_buffers) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond_empty, &mutex);
        }
        int conn_fd = accept_or_die(listen_fd, (sockaddr_t *) &client_addr, (socklen_t *) &client_len);
        conn_fds[i] = conn_fd;
        i = (i + 1) % n_buffers;
        open_connections++;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond_full);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        printf("New connection opened.\n");
    }
        return 0;
}
```

The main thread takes care of accepting new connections and places their corresponding file descriptors into a buffer.
Through the command line arguments, the user specifies how many additional threads will be created and how big the buffer for the file descriptors will be. This new threads will respond to and close the new connections via `manage_conn`.

For now I'm testing the server with these arguments:

> -b 20 -t 5

5 additional threads will manage the connections and the buffer size is 20.

I execute the server program and a client program that tells the server to run spin.cgi (a program that just spins for the specified amount of time).

Normally, less than 5 threads run and the main one accepts the new connection request but everything gets blocked after that.

[image]

First of all, I don't understand what happens to the other threads that are never executed.

However, my main question is why the threads that were waiting for cond_full never wake up when it is supposed to be signaled by the main thread after opening a new connection.

I already tried to debug this, but the error never shows up (I suppose it is because of the different timing).

Edit:

I forgot to initialize the mutex and the condition variables. I already changed that but the problem is is still there.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond_empty = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond_full = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

Comment: The *first* thing I'd do is properly initialize your mutex and condition variables prior to entering your code logic. ether use the static initializers (ex: `pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` and `pthread_cond_t cond_empty = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;`) or via the API.

Comment: @WhozCraig I already fixed that but it's not working yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line was causing the problem.

```
int conn_fd = accept_or_die(listen_fd, (sockaddr_t *) &client_addr, (socklen_t *) &client_len);
```

It kept waiting for a new connection request, but at the same time it was keeping the mutex locked, so it didn't let the other threads run.

What I did to prevent this is unlock the mutex before executing it and lock again after it accepted a new request.

```
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    int conn_fd = accept_or_die(listen_fd, (sockaddr_t *) &client_addr, (socklen_t *) &client_len);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
```